# Getting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6] Application startup exception in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-core-3.0

I am getting below error while running Web API Application with .NET Core 3.0. I have implemented Attribute Routing and using the below code in Configure method of statup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
System.ArgumentException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternParser.Parse(String pattern)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternFactory.Parse(String pattern)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Template.TemplateParser.Parse(String routeTemplate)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Template.TemplateParser.Parse(String routeTemplate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.InferParameterBindingInfoConvention.ParameterExistsInAnyRoute(ActionModel action, String parameterName)   
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.InferParameterBindingInfoConvention.InferBindingSourceForParameter(ParameterModel parameter)
```

Thanks!

Comment: My app runs fine from VS.  But gives me this error in docker compose-up command.

Comment: I am not sure at this point but i think it must be some configuration issue. Sorry i just saw your message. I think you already solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. I forgot to add the closing "}" for one of the Http Action in my Attribute Routing.

```
[HttpPost("{id}/like/{recipientId")]
```

as you can see the closing "}" is missing after recipientId. I think the error is totally misleading.

Comment: How is the error misleading? It told you *exactly* that

Comment: the error was pointing to startup.cs file for the below code            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });               and i was not able to figure out that the error was because of wrong route parameter value in the controller